# Problem collection in angular 6 using firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, angular6, record

```
this.afDB.collection('places/' + place.id ).add(place);
```

I have problem in collection ( ' places ' + place.id )

Place was added, but the collection came out place1537547932547
and I want it to come out in the folder place

Error in console : Collection references must have an odd number of segments

Comment: `this.afDB.doc('places/' + place.id).set(place);`

Answer (score 0):

solve the problem with

```
this.afDB.collection('places').doc('' + place.id ).set(place);
```